# Convert a nullptr to std::span

Tags: c++, nullptr, std-span

I have a `const z*    zs        = nullptr;`

I want to convert `zs`  to `std::span`

When I try to do `std::span<const z>(zs)`  I get an error saying

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::span::span(const z* const&)’

How do I convert to zs to `std::span`

I tried `std::span<const z>(zs[0])` it seems to compile. Is that way correct?

Comment: How do you expect a `span` over `nullptr` to behave? This seems broken by design.

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer (which is sort of what you are trying to do `*(zs + 0)` where `zs = nullptr`) is undefined behavior. That's why you have no error from the compiler.

Comment: The error message is straightforward: you can't construct a span given only a pointer value. It wouldn't matter if it pointed at a valid element rather than being `nullptr` - the problem is that a span has to know how many elements to span over. Pointers, by design, do not store any such information. The question is, *why* do you want to do this conversion? If you simply want to have a zero-length span, then there is no reason to set up a pointer in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

`std::span` has a constructor which takes a pointer and a size, use that:

`std::span<const z>(zs, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a length to go along with your pointer. A null pointer points to 0 elements. Are you reassigning `sz` somewhere?

An empty `span` is constructed from no arguments.

```
std::span<const z>{}
```